# 'MyApp' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

I am trying to add a link from one page to another page. But it generating error of MyApp not registered while I have registered it in urls.py

Here is my .html file:

```
<body>      
    <h1>Hello world </h1>
    
    <h1> <a href = " {% url 'MyApp: Variable' %} "> Variable Page</a> </h1>
</body>
```

Here is my urls.py(MyApp) file:

```
apps_name = 'MyApp'

urlpatterns = [    
                 
        path('', views.simpleView, name = 'Example'),     #domain.com\MyApp
        path('variable/', views.VariableView, name = 'Variable')
```

Here is my urls.py(Mysite) file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('MyApp/', include('MyApp.urls')),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

and here is my error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /MyApp/
'MyApp' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyApp/
Django Version: 3.2.14
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
'MyApp' is not a registered namespace
Exception Location: C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\DJango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py, line 82, in reverse
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\DJango\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.9
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\DJango\\MySite',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\DJango\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\DJango\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 30 Jul 2022 09:43:01 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your urls.py file, it should be `app_name` not `apps_name`.

```py
app_name = 'MyApp' # see here

urlpatterns = [    
                 
        path('', views.simpleView, name = 'Example'),     #domain.com\MyApp
        path('variable/', views.VariableView, name = 'Variable')
```

You should also remove the space in your `{% url 'MyApp: Variable' %}` line.